# Using List.InsertRange() or List.Insert() appears to be editing the list it inserts from

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm trying to insert a 2D list into another 2D list starting at a point specified by x,y.

ex:

```
List A = {{1,1,1,1},
          {1,1,1,1},
          {1,1,1,1},
          {1,1,1,1}}
List B = {{2,2,2,2},
          {2,2,2,2},
          {2,2,2,2},
          {2,2,2,2}}

MergeLists(A, B, 0, 0) would give:
{{2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1},
 {2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1},
 {2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1},
 {2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1}}

MergeLists(A, B, 2, 0) would give:
{{1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1},
 {1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1},
 {1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1},
 {1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1}}

*My code adds an additional 0 at the end of each line but I'm not worried about that.
MergeLists(A, B, 5, 0) would give:
{{1,1,1,0,2,2,2,2},
 {1,1,1,0,2,2,2,2},
 {1,1,1,0,2,2,2,2},
 {1,1,1,0,2,2,2,2}}

MergeLists(A, B, 0, 1) would give:
{{1,1,1,1},
 {2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1},
 {2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1},
 {2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1},
 {2,2,2,2}}

MergeLists(A, B, 0, 5) would give:
{{1,1,1,1},
 {1,1,1,1},
 {1,1,1,1},
 {1,1,1,1},
 {0},
 {2,2,2,2},
 {2,2,2,2},
 {2,2,2,2},
 {2,2,2,2}}
```

My Code works well for the x direction but breaks when y>0. Instead it seems to add the last list it merged to the beginning of the next list it's going to merge.

```
MergeLists(A, B, 0, 1) erroneously gives:
{{1,1,1,1},
 {2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1},
 {2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
 {2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
 {2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}}
```

Here's My Code:

```
public class StrTester{
    private List<List<int>> grid;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){
        grid = new List<List<int>>();
        List<List<int>> newGrid = new List<List<int>>();
        List<int> ints = new List<int>();
        for(int i=1; i<21; i++){
            ints.Add(i);
            if(i%4 == 0){
                newGrid.Add(ints);
                ints = new List<int>();
            }
        }
        MergeLists(newGrid, 0, 0);
        Print(newGrid);
        MergeLists(newGrid, 0, 1);
        Print(grid);
    }

    private void MergeLists(List<List<int>> newInts, int x, int y){
        if(grid.Count == 0){
            grid = new List<List<int>>(newInts);
        } else {
            while(y + newInts.Count >= grid.Count){
                    grid.Add(new List<int>());
                }
            foreach(List<int> ints in grid){
                while(ints.Count < x){
                    ints.Add(0);
                }
            }
            foreach(List<int> newIntRow in newInts){
                Print(newIntRow);
                grid[y].InsertRange(x, new List<int>(newIntRow));
                Print(newIntRow);
                y++;
                Print(newIntRow);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Print(List<List<int>> printGrid){
        string str = "";
        foreach(List<int> lInt in printGrid){
            foreach(int i in lInt){
                str += i + ", ";
            }
            Debug.Log(str);
            str = "";
        }
    }

    private void Print(List<int> printList){
        string str = "";
        foreach(int i in printList){
            str += i + ", ";
        }
        Debug.Log("this line is: " + str);
    }
}
```

Note that this was written to be used in the unity engine so if you're testing this on the console you'll need to change the "Start" method to "Main" and the "Debug.Log" in the Print methods.

Comment: `grid = new List<List<int>>(newInts);` creates a new list containing references to the existing lists in `newInts`. Thus, after the first call to MergeLists(), the list in `grid[0]` is the same actual object as the list in `newGrid[0]`. If you insert items into `grid[0]`, you are inserting items into `newGrid[0]`. You need to duplicate the "child" lists as well.

Comment: In Start(), insert this line between the first call to `MergeLists(newGrid, 0, 0);` and the line `Print(newGrid);`: `grid[0].Insert(0, 99);`. `Print(newGrid);` will show you a 99 in the first column of the first row of `newGrid`.

Comment: If I were you, I would write a method `public static List<List<int>> DuplicateGrid(List<List<int>> grid)` which loops through the outer list and clones all the inner lists into it, and then returns the new "deep" copy. Get that debugged, and you'll be able to rely on it whenever you duplicate a grid.

Comment: Just tested it and it works great thanks so much Ed!